# 'CloseToolhelp32Snapshot': identifier not found

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-studio, winapi

I am using a memory monitoring library based on "WIN32 tool help functions".

In its source code there are calls to `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()`, `Heap32ListFirst()`, `Heap32ListNext()`, and `CloseToolhelp32Snapshot()`.

**My problem is that there is no prototype for CloseToolhelp32Snapshot() in the associated windows header file.**

I'm trying to compile for windows PC platform (Win7 precisely, but i assume it makes no difference with XP).

I searched on internet, and some chinese guys say i have to use `CloseHandle()` on a PC platform while some others say it generates a memory leak.

**How can I properly close the handle once i used it ?**

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for [`CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682489%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says:

> To destroy the snapshot, use the *CloseHandle* function.

`CloseToolhelp32Snapshot` would appear to be for WinCE/Mobile only.